# how to check whether an array of objects is NULL for some index in java

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I am new to Java programming and I am unable to check whether for some i < length(of array) , whether arr[i] is valid or NULL .

Lets define a class student that has instance variables as name and roll number.

If the array of Students has student object stored at positions 1 , 3 and 5 , How do I , using a for loop from i = 0 to i = 5 print the name and roll numbers without having an NZEC (knowing that arr[0] , arr[2] and arr[4] does not have anything stored) .

I know that in c++ , we can directly check using :

```
if (arr[i] != NULL)
    print(name,roll)
```

But , how do I do it in Java ?

Comment: use `null` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: Replace `NULL` with `null`, and the same code is going to work.

Comment: and change print by System.out.print or System.out..println

Comment: @Lothar I'm using System.out.println and that print was more of a pseudocode

Comment: You want us to *understand* your problem. You seem to have a problem with REAL code, so you please use real code. As in [mcve]. Your question is confusingly unclear enough already - no need to further complicate things by dumping sort-of pseudo code.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh , dasblinkenlight
Even using the null (thanks for pointing out the syntax error) doesn't work and I'm still getting Runtime Error !

Comment: [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve] [mcve]

Comment: https://ideone.com/MpO0Ja
This has my complete code if anyone want to see !
This code prints marks of assignments ( of three types) along with their serial ID's

Comment: Sorry. But you do **not** LINK to your code. You step back and edit your question to include that [mcve] thing. The idea is that questions and answers here are self-contained. Links break.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, Java is a case sensitive programming language and the null keyword is lowercase. Thus comparing `if(arr[i] != NULL)` would give you a syntax error, you want to type `if(arr[i] != null)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] != null){
       System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

These kind of errors and mistakes can be easily avoided by using an IDE. IDEs usually find errors in your code before you compile it, and will point them out so you can fix them. Most IDEs will provide a possible solution to your problem in a addition to finding it, so you can't go wrong. I suggest you use [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/).

Comment: I disagree on the IDE thing. When you start learning a new language - learning about some pretty complex tool such as eclipse adds just a ton of complexity to an already full plage. And beyond that: an IDE prevents you from making a lot of core, basic experiences. When you already know some IDE, fine then use it. But when one is really completely new to things, then I would go with a simple editor and command line - at least for some weeks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Object[] arr = {obj1,null,obj2,obj3};
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(arr[i]!=null) {
    //Do what you want, obj is not null
} else {
    //Do what you want, obj is NULL!
}
```

Comment: www.ideone.com/MpO0Ja
Please go through my code once 
And please ignore the Compilation error due to the package in ideone !
I have tried using null instead of NULL but it still doesn't work !

Comment: That’s a lot of code to ask us to review! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The message “Main.java:305: error: class Question5 is public, should be declared in a file named Question5.java” means there’s a disagreement between the name of the class and the name of the file. How to fix that on IdeOne, I don’t know.

Comment: @OleV.V. , That code works fine on hackerearth interface and that error is not an issue . I just wanted someone to point out why I'm getting a Runtime Error in my code !

Comment: @KartikMadaan my code is tested using an array of String. If you replace first line with:
             String[] arr = {"a",null,"b","c"}
It will works also on your pc. If you use an object instead of Strings probably error is linked to this object. Can you post more information about that?

Comment: @KartikMadaan, we’d love to help, but it requires an effort on your part. If you are having a different problem from the one in this question, go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (again), then ask a new question.